# Emulate VBA Replace function in MDX

Tags: mdx, mdx-query

There is an invalid character in a name field in the MDX data, and I don't have access to change the setting on the server to change the effect on invalid characters.

> '', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 12151241.

While I can use some VBA functions, the essential replace is not available.

```
member measures.FName as replace([Agent].[First Name].[First Name],'→','')
```

What options do I have to allow the query to execute by either skipping the entries, or replacing/deleting the character?

```
iif(instr([Agent].[First Name].[First Name],'→')>0,NULL,[Agent].[First Name].[First Name])
```

returns `#Error`